# How to search for a pattern between lines 1500 to 2500?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have 8 files, and each contains around 2000 lines. I want to search the particular word in these files between line number 1500 to 2500.

The output should look like:

```
sample_1.txt :

1510:declare var testing


sample_2.txt :

1610:declare var testing


sample_7.txt :

1610:declare var testing


sample_10.txt :

1710:declare var testing
```

Is it possible to use `grep` for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    begin = ARGV[1]
    end = ARGV[2]
    pattern=ARGV[3]
    ARGV[1] = ARGV[2] = ARGV[3] = ""
}

NR > end {exit}

NR == 1 {
    print FILENAME " :\n"
}

NR >= begin {
    if ($0 ~ pattern) 
        print NR ":" $0
}
```

Call it like this:

```
./rangegrep 1500 2000 'declare var testing' sample*.txt
```

The search string can be a regular expression.

**Edit:**

I changed from range checking the line number to using `exit` as in [akira's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/237480/how-to-search-for-a-pattern-between-lines-1500-to-2500/237484#237484) since the `exit` will stop processing lines at the end of the range and save time by not reading the rest of the lines in the file.

Comment: is it possible with using grap instead of program,

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: 'print FILENAME' could be put into the BEGIN { } as well... @bharanikumar: why are you so obsessed with grep? use the right tool for the problem and do not try to use the one hammer you have found somewhere and now everything you see is nails.

Comment: @akira: From `man gawk`: "FILENAME  is  undefined  inside  the  BEGIN  block (unless set by getline)." @bharanikumar: You could do it with `grep` if you used `head` *and* `tail`, but you'd lose line numbering and filename labeling.

Comment: Though it's more efficient to write this as one script I can't help but thinking that this is a missing tool. As a complement to head and tail, a tool that gives you a specific range of lines or bytes out of the middle of a stream (based on offset from the start). We could call it torso or thorax.

Comment: @phogg: I like "torso"! However, "thorax" excludes the abdomen and we can't do that because it's the "guts" of the file that we're really interested in. Having a tool like "torso" probably violates at least one principle in the [Unix philosphy](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html) since `head|tail` does the job adequately.

Comment: Combining head and tail with a pipe does this quite neatly, but the problem is retaining the line numbers is tricky. Sed can also do this quite simply, but it can't print the filename.

Comment: @Alan: Also, I find line-number output in `sed` to be unsatisfactory.

Comment: It's a shame you can't use it in a pattern match or substitution.

Comment: You're all quite right, but just for fun I added an answer using `torso`. I sidestepped the line number question by pretending that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` does what you want:

```
% awk 'NR < 1500 { next }; NR > 2500 { exit}; \
    /pattern/ { printf("%s:\n%d:%s\n", FILENAME, NR, $0); }' \
    sample_*.txt
```

to have as much space as you provided in your desired output, you just have to add as many `\n` to the printf statement...

Comment: I upvoted your answer earlier, but forgot to leave this comment. I like your `next` and `exit` better than my range checking. The `exit` can speed things up quite a bit under some circumstances. I'm going to blatantly copy those into my answer. OK, fine, with attribution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Without using `awk` how about some shell script + `sed`:

```
for f in sample_*.txt ; do echo "$f : " ; \
    sed -ne '1500,2500{/pattern/{=;p}}' $f ; \
    echo ; \
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Purely In The Interests Of Science, I present an implementation of `torso`, the logical middle between `head` and `tail`.

In practice, as others have noted, this is really unnecessary since you can get the desired output yourself by a trivial combination of `head` and `tail`.

```
#!/bin/sh

usage () {
    printf "$0: $0 [-c <byte> -C <byte>] [-n <line> -N <line>] file [file ... ]\n"
}

while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    case "$1" in
            -c|--byte-start) shift ; start="$1" ; mode=byte ; shift ;;
            -C|--byte-end) shift ; end="$1" ; mode=byte ; shift ;;
            -n|--line-start) shift ; start="$1" ; mode=line ; shift ;;
            -N|--line-end) shift ; end="$1" ; mode=line ; shift ;;
                --) shift ;;
            -*) printf "bad option '%s'\n" "$1" ; usage ; exit 201 ;;
                *) files=("${files[@]}" "$1") ; shift ;;
         esac
done

if [ $start -gt $end ] ; then
    printf "end point cannot be before start point\n"
    usage
    exit 202
fi

head_cmd=
tail_cmd=
end=$((end - start))
if [ $mode = "line" ] ; then
    head_cmd="-n $end"
    tail_cmd="-n +$start"
elif [ $mode = "byte" ] ; then
    head_cmd="-c $end"
    tail_cmd="-c +$start"
fi

if [ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ] ; then
    cat - | tail $tail_cmd | head $head_cmd
else
    tail $tail_cmd "${files[@]}" | head $head_cmd
fi
```

To keep it topical, here's how to use `torso` to solve the question:

```
torso -n 1500 -N 2500 input_file | grep -n "test"
```

Or for output conforming to the requirements

```
for file in sample_{1,2,7,10} ; do
     printf "\n\n%s:\n\n" "$file"
     torso -n 1500 -N 2500 "$file" | grep -n "test"
done
```

You may begin your criticisms... now!

Comment: You could put `cat -n` in there somewhere to get line numbering.

Comment: I worry about the possibility of false positives in the grep match if I do that. Probably it should be an additional switch. What "line number" means when there are multiple files is also a question.

Comment: @Dennis would have made sure I saw your comment. I just happened upon it.